# Windows NT user or group 'DOMAIN\USER' not found?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I am trying to create users on a SQL server from an Active Directory group as an application I am working with does not natively support Windows authentication and relies upon individual logins being created on the SQL server, as application level permissions are managed in the application rather than using SQL roles. Due to this, each user that is to access the application needs their own user creating against the SQL instance that the applications database is on, so that the user can then be assigned individual permissions within the application.

I am reading the list of users from the Active Directory group we have designated using the following;

`exec master..xp_logininfo 'domain\groupname', 'members'`

This returns output similar to the following;

```
account name    type  privilege  mapped login name  permission path
DOMAIN\USER     user  user       DOMAIN\USER        DOMAIN\GROUPNAME
```

For the most part, the users returned in this list can be created on the SQL instance without any drama. I am creating the users as SQL accounts using `sp_grantlogin` in the first instance, before moving on to allow each new login access to the application database. However, a handful of users are being reported as not existing. I get the following error as a result of running `sp_grantlogin`;

```
Msg 15401, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_grantlogin, Line 49
Windows NT user or group 'DOMAIN\USER' not found. Check the name again.
```

Obviously in the above error message, I have removed the actual username. Why would `xp_logininfo` return a user that cannot be created with `sp_grantlogin`? Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324321/en-us

Comment: the user definitely exists in AD, the potential for the suser_sid being a duplicate is unknown, as select suser_sid('DOMAIN\USER') returns NULL, the domain controller is available (I assume) as I'm able to run xp_logininfo against it, and I am using the same case as is returned from xp_logininfo when I am trying to create the user...

Answer (score 2):

I can give you my advice from doing this in Windows 7 although it may not be relevant.

The problem I had was that I had renamed the user account in the Windows UI. The name appeared correctly in Windows, and I used the new name to log on. But behind the scenes it was still using the old name which was what SQL Server was looking for.

I struggled with this for HOURS before I finally worked it out!!

Answer (score 2):

This just means that the user is not in the Administrator group. If your problem is like mine where your Active Directory in on a different Virtual Machine, and your SQL Server on another. And you have joined Active Directory Domain to your SQL Server Virtual Machine, then you have to do the following on your SQL Server Virtual MAchine.

1. Navigate to **Tools** --> **Computer Management**.
2. The windows opens, Expand **System Tools** --> **Local Users and Groups**.
3. Click on **Groups** and you should see a list of groups to the right
   column of the window.
4. Double click **Administrator**, a new window opens and you will notice that the linked User  is not under there.
5. Click **Add**, new window opens. Here, under location, you may chose to change
   location of your domain.
6. Click **Advanced**, a log in prompt opens, simply log in with you administrator Virtual Machine account.
7. Click **Find Now** with all fields as is. From a list of users presented, double click the user imported from Active Directory and click **Ok**.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar case, the same error code 15401, but in this case what I was doing was adding users from the Domain, into a group in the server where I had SQL; so then just add the group to SQL engine with the same ROLE.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [localhost\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Windows NT user or group 'localhost\Administrators' not found. Check the name again.
```

Then in the link [PRB: Use BUILTIN\Group to Grant Access to Predefined Windows NT Groups](https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/kb/216808)

I found the issue, so the solution was:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [BUILTIN\Administrators]
GO
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

I believe this is great to diminish the number of login accounts, and have a more manageable number of users assigned to the roles in the SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you change the case of the login name before using `sp_grantlogin`?

If you have a case sensitive server collation, then the case of the AD user nneds to be specified in exactly the right case.

You can find the server collation by doing:

```
select serverproperty('collation')
```

If you do have a case sensitive server collation, and you don't mess with the case, there is probably a mismatch with what `xp_logininfo` is returning and the actual case in AD. In which case, try creating the user with variations on the case.

If none of this applies, look into the account. Is it disabled, can you log in with it, etc.. If suser_sid() returns null, then there must be some kind of problem with it.

Comment: no, the actual login name is being set into a variable and then sp_grantlogin is called with the variable, when I test the process manually I copy and paste. The SQL collation in the environment I'm running this in is case insensitive. The case of the username as reported by xp_logininfo matches the case of the username as it is presented in Active Directory

Comment: Is the account disabled? Have you tried logging on with the account?

Comment: account is active - I myself cannot log into the account as the account but the user n question can log in and does do on a daily basis

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this error for users, who was:

1. created in AD
2. granted some SQL permissions
3. renamed in AD

Then I try to add this new, renamed user account name to the same server/database, error Msg 15401, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_grantlogin, Line 49 appears.

I have followed steps in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324321/en-us and this command returned old user account name befor rename:

```
SELECT name FROM syslogins WHERE sid = SUSER_SID ('YourDomain\YourLogin')
```

it returned
YourDomain\OldLogin

after executing
exec sp_revokelogin 'YourDomain\OldLogin'

problem was fixed, sp_grantlogin now works ok.

PS as another test method I suggest running sp_grantlogin remotely, from another server. It may succeed to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a non-English language, or have been using one on your machine, you might have to ***localize*** the user details you're trying to use.

E.g. `[NT AUTHORITY\Network Service]` on a Swedish machine is `[NT INSTANS\Nätverkstjänst]`.

Spent hours trying to figure out why `BUILTIN\`, `NT AUTHORITY\`, `<MachineName>\` etc. didn't work.

Comment: Where you able to put tthem in english language ?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the length of the login. In `Domain\User` syntax, Windows uses the so called pre-Windows 2000 syntax. That syntax limits the length of the username to 20 characters. You have to truncate the username to the first 20 characters and then it should work, like so:

```
Domain\Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Becomes

```
Domain\Abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```