# Can't see Active Directory groups within SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, active-directory

I'm trying to add an SQL login for an Active Directory group.

I can see the group in AD (Operational Managers)...[image]

...but the same group isn't visible within the SQL...

[image]

I'm not an IT admin, I just do SQL stuff and both of our IT guys are out of the office this week.

I'm just wondering if there's anything I can do to add the login group without having domain access to Active Directory (other than adding each group member individually)?

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089617/windows-nt-user-or-group-domain-user-not-found

Comment: Why don't you create login just writing T-SQL code instead of using GUI? CREATE LOGIN [your_dom\your_group] from WINDOWS

Comment: I tried this but I've got no way of testing it - i might just wait until the IT guys are back!

Comment: What does it mean, " I've got no way of testing it"? Did you execute a command? Was the login created? Do you see in in sys.server_principals?

Comment: I added it using T-SQL and it appeared in the logins on the left - I guess if I've used 'from WINDOWS', it must be correct and linked to an AD account??

Comment: Of course it's correct. Login was created successfully, this means it was found in AD, otherwise y'd get an error

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Check the 'Group type' of the missing group. Only groups of type "Security" can be used for permissions. If the 'Group type' is "Distribution" it will not show up in the search since it cannot be used for assigning permissions.
2. If the server is joined to the same domain as the group then ignore this, but if the group and the server are on different domains, then check the 'Group scope'. The server won't be able to see a "Domain local" group on another domain.

[image]